# onDraw not called in custom view extending view not viewgroup

Tags: android, view, custom-view

There are a lot of similar questions and therefore this may seem like a duplicate but please read first.

I have gone through all of the following questions and it didn't work for me

1. [onDraw() is not called in custom View](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17470620/9640177)
2. [invalidate not redrawing view on api 25](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41441542/9640177)
3. [Android Custom Layout - onDraw() never gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13056331/9640177)
4. [view.invalidate() not working to redraw imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5540853/9640177)
5. [Why onDraw is not called after invalidate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17595546/9640177)
6. [Android View Canvas onDraw not performed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12253952/9640177)

Let me clarify further

1. I am extending View class not any ViewGroup like LinearLayout etc
2. when I call `invalidate()` from `onTouchEvent` it runs fine
3. when I call `invalidate()` from another function of the same class (`undo()`) `invalidate()` doesn't work
4. I also tried calling `postInvalidate()` and also called invalidate using `postDelayed(new Runnable ... invalidate()` nothing seems to work.
5. after touching undo button when I touch the view it draws the expected result immediately.

Any suggestion on what could be the issue?

code looks something like below

```
public boolean undo() {
    if (undoStack.isEmpty()) return false;
    redoStack.push(undoStack.pop());
    if (redoStack.size() >= MAX_STACK_SIZE) redoStack.removeElementAt(0);
    // invalidate();
    postInvalidate();
    return true;
}
```

here undoStack holds the previous bitmaps that were drawn

I can say that undo and onDraw are working fine as I get the expected results when I touch the view after clicking on undo button. Also I am calling this function from the main Thread and not background thread or async task.

Any suggestions please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have verified, using the log (or the debugger), that `invalidate()` is executing, and `onDraw()` is not executing? I want to make sure you did not draw these conclusions by simply observing the `View` contents.

Comment: It could be because of returning zero as width/height of view in onMeasure https://stackoverflow.com/a/65381220/2700239